# How does np.random.standard_normal(x) work?

Tags: python, numpy, random, random-seed

I want to get an understanding of the maths used in the backend to get from the uniformly distributed random numbers produced by np.random vs the standard normal distribution of random numbers produced by np.standard_normal? How does Python convert between these distributions as several methods exist like Inverse Transform and Box Muller?

Comment: Are you asking about Python or NumPy? `np.random.standard_normal` is part of NumPy, but you ask "How does Python convert ...", so I'm a bit confused. (Python does have its own standard library `random` module and functions for generating normal variates, but it uses different algorithms from NumPy.)

Comment: Sorry I should've been more clear. I'm interested in learning how np.random.standard_normal converts between uniform distribution and standard normal distribution.

Comment: From my knowledge of reading docs, the uniform distribution is produced by the Mersenne Twister algorithm but I couldn't find information on converting from this to the standard normal

Comment: I believe that in the current implementation it uses a Ziggurat algorithm. The source is here: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/92b880f64024c0694c69a6397568ce758102f9d8/numpy/random/src/distributions/distributions.c#L137-L170 . (And the underlying PRNG is no longer Mersenne Twister by default.)

Comment: Thanks - That's exactly what I was looking for, The Ziggurat algorithm seems to be mostly based around the accept-reject method as opposed to inverse transform which was my initial assumption. Do you know what the underlying PRNG is now?

Comment: From my research, it seems to be the Permuted Congruential Generator but I wanted to confirm this is correct

Comment: That's correct. It's covered in the documentation: https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/random/index.html